# Javascript checking only the first item of an array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array of arrays, i.e. `[ [1,2], [1,3] ]`  and I want to check if is there any 1 as the first element of a subarray. It doesn't matter if it is a `[1,2]` or `[1,3]`. I'm interested only in the 1's existence. Sure I could use some loops to do this, but I wonder if is there an elegant "built-in" way to do this in js, something like:

```
arr.includes([1, _]) // returns true if is there any 1 as first element of an array
```

Comment: `arr.some(([a, _]) => a === 1)`

Comment: Nothing wrong with using a loop and breaking the loop if condition met. Built in methods are a bit easier to write but won't have greater efficiency

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) is something you are looking for.

Code example:

```js
const data = [[1, 3], [1, 5]] 

const res = data.some( ([a, _]) => a === 1 ) // less elegant alternative:
                                             // .some(e => e[0] === 1)

console.log(res)
```

Comment: The `, _` is pointless. You can just use `[a]`

Comment: Yes, that's true, but it better match OPs expectation.